# how to sort a dataset in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, multidimensional-array

I am using PDO to connect to my tables in the database. So I wrote a quick function to return the results that was return from the data table. Yes I can use SORT BY in my query to sort the results but i want to avoid that in this query because this query pull information for a large table.

*** First I need to be able to sort this data set at the user end. so I need somehow to sort by different columns so I can sort by column "fullName" or sort by "userID" or "createdDate"

so when PDO fetch the results and return the array I want to sort those.

*** Second question where in this function I do a free results or do I free them outside the query?

```
function getDataSet($query, $connection){

    $cmd = $connection->query( $query );
    return $cmd->fetchAll();  //PDO::FETCH_ASSOC

}
```

then I can call this function by simply doing

```
$dataset = getDataSet("select * from users", $db)
```

in my first question i want to sort $dataset.

Comment: what do you mean by "for a large table"?

Comment: Let me just get this straight, you have a database system that is optimised for sorting data and you want to do it in a system that is not optimised. Can you explain WHY you want to avoid the efficient solution and instead use the inefficient one?

Comment: @didierc more than a hundred records!

Comment: I can think of no scenario where it would not be faster to `ORDER BY` the query. This can also, of course, also be made dynamic based on input from the user.

Comment: Guys they query in my question is not what i am using. my actual query involves 5 joins and one of those table has 5 Million records and the second table is 500k so insted of doing a sort in my query i want to handle it using PHP so I won't add more to the query. the tables are optimized correctly.

Comment: Sorry we still don't agree. If the tables are optimized correctly (the correct indexes and the like) it will still be faster to sort in SQL. If you REALLY have a supernatural scenario where it is not, you will have to show us the REAL stuff so that we can help you.

Comment: Still ordering on the DB will be much faster.
And one more thing. If you will get huge amount of data and do operations on it like sorting it with PHP will get a lot of memory.
Sorting data via SQL and geting it one by one will consume much less memory.

Answer (score 0):

I do NOT agree with you on not using "ORDER BY" in your SQL statement. But anyway, you can try this:

```
$tmp_dataset = array();
foreach($dataset as $data)
{
    $tmp_dataset[ $data['name_of_column'] ] = $data;
}

$dataset = $tmp_dataset;

ksort($dataset);
```

Comment: And this is why we don't like this idea. Check this out. For 1000 rows you must set whole 1000 records in the momory and do temporary array with next 1000 rows. This way you will use 2x more memory.

ORDERING IN THE SQL QUERY WILL NOT AFFECT THE SPEED OF YOUR QUERY, no matter how complicated is your query (only if you do some string manipulation in order).

Comment: If you don't believe do the full query with and without order. I bet that the difference will be funny. Oh, and don't forget to measure the time needed to sort the same data on PHP side and share with us :]

Comment: I see your point now. I always thought Sort by will make the query slower. Thank you for your clarification. I guess that left the second question which where in my function I free the results?

Comment: I did mention that he should use order by. @Mike please clarify your second question

Comment: @redmoon7777, When i use order by to sort by a datetime field it increase my run time by at least 10 second. please take a peak at this other post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15512839/order-by-datetime-makes-the-query-very-slow where i had posted my actual query and my column types. My second question was when in my above code I can free the results that was returned by PDO

Comment: your other post is about query optimisation, so I can't answer it here. I'm not sure I understand you second question, what do you mean by "when in my above code I can free the results that was returned by PDO", what do you mean by free the results ?

Comment: OK Mike, now you have pointed us to your "real" question, I have offered an answer on that one. The simple fact is that, because you have a limit and an order by, you will get a different (and unpredictable) result set if you do not include the ORDER BY. Hopefully my answer to your other question will solve your problem, but if it doesn't, leave a comment on that question and I will give you another method (slightly less pretty IMO) that is however guaranteed to work and give you the performance improvement that you need.