# ORDER BY datetime makes the query very slow

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I am trying to pull data from multiple tables and when I user ORDER BY a datetime field it return the results after at least 10 seconds but if I do the same query without ORDER BY then it return the results for under 2 seconds.

This is my current query

```
SELECT
ph.call_subject AS callSubject,
ac.account_name AS accountName,
DATE_FORMAT(ph.trigger_on, "%c/%e/%Y %h:%i %p") AS triggerOn,
ind.name AS industry,
cc.call_code_name AS callCode
FROM phone_calls AS ph
INNER JOIN accounts AS ac ON ph.account_id = ac.account_id
INNER JOIN industries AS ind ON ind.industry_id = ac.industry_id
INNER JOIN call_codes AS cc ON ph.call_code_id = cc.call_code_id
WHERE ac.status = 1 AND ph.status = 1 AND ph.owner_id = 1 AND ac.do_not_call = 0
AND ph.trigger_on BETWEEN '2012-11-19 00:00:00' AND '2013-03-19 23:59:59'
ORDER BY ph.trigger_on ASC LIMIT 0,1000
```

the following fields are all of the type INT(11) UNSIGNED

```
ph.account_id
ac.account_id
ind.industry_id
ac.industry_id
ph.call_code_id
cc.call_code_id
ph.owner_id
```

The following fields are all of the type tinyint(1)

```
ac.status 
ph.status
ac.do_not_call
```

this field is a datetime type

```
ph.trigger_on
```

Please note that has accounts 300K records and phone_calls has 5 million records.
What can I do to preform this ORDER BY faster? note that all of my where clause fields, all my ON clause and ph.trigger_on are indexed. and I am using InnoDB storage engine not MyIsam.

Thanks

Comment: Please include the table definitions so we can see what types you've chosen and the indexing in place

Comment: Please check my post again as I updated it with some field types

Comment: could you please show us what EXPLAIN returns ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please try this:

1. Build an index on the columns `(phone_calls.trigger_on, phone_calls.status, phone_calls.owner_id)` Call it `pcto`
2. Change your FROM clause to:

```
    FROM phone_calls AS ph FORCE INDEX (pcto)
```

This is the ideal. If it does not work, then add a comment and I will give you another method that it guaranteed to work and give you the performance improvement that you need.

**PLEASE NOTE: It doesn't matter (and indeed does no good) to have indexes built on "every" column in your query. MySQL can only use ONE index per table (or more correctly per table alias). You need to build the indexes that we are telling you to.**

Comment: Okay, Wow that did the trick! Can you please tell me what is the second idea that you had as option B so i can have another trick to use when running into this issue again in a different senarios? Thanks you.

Comment: The other method, only to be used if REALLY needed (and it is VERY RARE that it is EVER needed) is to replace the FROM clause with a sub-select thus "FROM (SELECT * FROM phone_calls phs WHERE phs.status = 1 AND phs.owner_id = 1 ORDER BY phs.trigger_on) AS ph". You still need the correct index built as in my answer. Incidentally, now you have built the correct index, try the query WITHOUT the "FORCE INDEX pcto". You will likely find that it still works fine. Just having indexes is not enough, you need to have sensible ones.

Comment: Thank you so much you have Ben a lot of help :)

Answer (score 3):

If you have a LIMIT of 5 rows then without the order the query can grab the first 5 rows it finds that match your other conditions.

If you have an ORDER BY clause it has to look at all the rows matching your other conditions and pick the 5 lowest.

Comment: I just updated my post and change the limit. I had limit 5 for testing purposes but it will be pulling a lot more that 5. So how can I use sort the results without loosing this speed factor?

Comment: Basically you can't.  The time that it takes with the ORDER is the actual time for running the full query.  Having the LIMIT without the ORDER was just disguising this.  If you have available memory in your application you may find it faster to query all of the rows without the ORDER and sort in your application.  See this doc on temp tables http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/internal-temporary-tables.html.  If MySQL is building a temp table on disk for your query it will probably be faster to put everything in memory in your application then sort it there.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience the fastest way to get performance from an SQL query is to simplify it into multiple steps. Take advantage of temporary tables and reduce the number of joins and operations per step(Eat memory, get speed). Forgive me for possible syntax errors below as I haven't used MySQL for a long time now, but you could rewrite your query as follows:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE scratch1 AS (
    SELECT
            ph.call_subject AS callSubject,
            ac.account_name AS accountName,
            DATE_FORMAT(ph.trigger_on, "%c/%e/%Y %h:%i %p") AS triggerOn,
            ac.industry_id,
            ph.call_code_id
    FROM
            phone_calls AS ph
            INNER JOIN accounts AS ac ON ph.account_id = ac.account_id
    WHERE   
            ac.status = 1 AND ph.status = 1 AND ph.owner_id = 1 AND ac.do_not_call = 0
            AND ph.trigger_on BETWEEN '2012-11-19 00:00:00' AND '2013-03-19 23:59:59' )

ALTER TABLE scratch1 ADD industry VARCHAR(255)
ALTER TABLE scratch1 ADD callCode VARCHAR(255)

UPDATE scratch1 s JOIN industries ind ON ind.industry_id = s.industry_id
SET s.industry = ind.name

UPDATE scratch1 s JOIN call_codes cc ON cc.call_code_id = s.call_code_id
SET s.callCode = cc.call_code_name

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE scratch2 AS (
    SELECT * FROM scratch1 ORDER BY triggerOn ASC )

SELECT * FROM scratch2 LIMIT 0, 1000
```

Comment: I can't use temp table like this. this is a good solution for a procedure not for query that will be executed 1000 a day by system uses. I never user a web app that is using temp table for regular queries.

Comment: Whilst in this case I agree that the proposed temp table will not help, it is rubbish to suggest that they are only useful for procedures and just because you "never user[SIC] a web app that is using temp table for regular queries", does not mean that they are not perfectly reasonable in some scenarios. Please to not come and ask experienced programmers for advice and then claim to know more than them. If you knew that much, you wouldn't need to ask here, would you!

Comment: @CaptainPayalytic, I did not say I know more than you! I only said that I never seen this happen for a query that is executed 1000 times a day. But u use your idea a lot in other things like for reporting and for temptory project. Thanks for trying to help :)

Answer (score 0):

This is to elaborate on Ersun's solution/comment.

Without the `order by`, SQL evaluates the query.  In this case, it is a bunch of joins.  Quite possibly, you have indexes on the join fields.  So, the query proceeds by reading a record from `phone_calls`, looking up the data, checking the filter conditions, and returning it.  It then goes to the the record and so on.  Overall, it probably reads a few thousands or tens of thousands of records.

With the `order by`, SQL has to evaluate *all* the records in the query.  It has to read *all* the phone calls, because the very last one might have the minimum value.  It then does the sorting and returns the right records.

You might be able to speed up the query by having an index on `phone_calls(status, owner_id, trigger_on)` to satisfy the `where` clause.

Comment: do you mean having one binary table for 3 columns? please note that owner_id value will change based on the user id that is logged in the site. I have the value 1 because this is my personal id.

Comment: @Mike . . . I mean that you want a multi-column index on the table.

Comment: But I already have them indexed. I have every column that is used in my column indexed.

Answer (score 0):

When you do a SELECT on (SELECT) `aka`, it's really like working on a temp table.  The example below has a few joins on one main large table.  This solution took the query down to 0.2 seconds vs 20 seconds when the ORDER BY is on the whole table query.

```
   SELECT * FROM (SELECT `cse_notes`.`notes_id`, `cse_notes`.`dateandtime`, 
    `cse_case`.`case_id`, `cse_case_notes`.`attribute`
    FROM  `cse_notes` 
    INNER JOIN  `cse_case_notes` 
    ON `cse_notes`.`notes_uuid` =  `cse_case_notes`.`notes_uuid`
    INNER JOIN `cse_case` 
    ON  `cse_case_notes`.`case_uuid` = `cse_case`.`case_uuid`
    WHERE `cse_notes`.`deleted` = 'N' AND `cse_case`.`case_id` = :case_id
    AND `cse_notes`.customer_id = :customer_id) notes
    ORDER BY `dateandtime` DESC
```

This is the bad query that runs very slowly.  I thought it was just fine, I had no idea the entire table must be sorted before filtering begins.  Indexing alone did not help.

```
    SELECT `cse_notes`.`notes_id`, `cse_notes`.`dateandtime`,
    `cse_case`.`case_id`, `cse_case_notes`.`attribute`    
    FROM  `cse_notes`     
    INNER JOIN  `cse_case_notes` ON `cse_notes`.`notes_uuid` =  `cse_case_notes`.`notes_uuid`    
    INNER JOIN `cse_case` ON  `cse_case_notes`.`case_uuid` = `cse_case`.`case_uuid`    
    WHERE `cse_notes`.`deleted` = 'N' 
    AND `cse_case`.`case_id` = :case_id    
    AND `cse_notes`.customer_id = :customer_id    
    ORDER BY `cse_notes`.dateandtime DESC LIMIT 0, 1000
```